# What do I do when my Nikon D7100 memory card access light remains on even when the camera is off and the camera does not function?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting

My new Nikon D7100 has stopped working. I reinserted a SD card (having uploaded the images to my computer) into the camera slot, as usual, and then tried to format as usual — but something has happened somewhere. The memory access light is staying on even when the camera is switched off. I have tried the card in another camera and it works okay. I have tried it in the No. 2 slot, but it's still not working. Have I made things worse by taking card out whilst the light is on? 
Can you help me?
thanks for any help 
Veronica

Comment: Hard to tell but have you tried removing the battery for a few seconds? Try that first and see if the camera operates normally without the card (obviously outside of shooting). Then put the card in. Finally try another card after doing the battery-removal thing.

Comment: This issue has cropped up before with Nikon cameras. It has something to do with the spring loaded part of the on-off switch. Let me see if i can find a link somewhere...

Comment: Different Nikon camera model, but the same problem: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42606/nikon-d90-back-led-keep-blinking/42614#42614

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be the issue with your D7100, but the *Nikon (Blinking) Green Light of Death* has cropped up on several previous Nikon models. Some folks have reported this fix:

- Turn the camera off, then pull the power switch all the way past *On* over to the *lightbulb*.
- Hold it there for a few seconds with your fingernail, then pull your fingernail straight off of it so that it 'flicks' back using the force of the spring. It should have enough energy from the spring to 'flick' all the way back to *Off*.
- Here's a link to [one discussion at dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/37539971) that discusses the issue and this solution.

Other online reports say that pressing the shutter button while the camera is off will stop the problem.

Others report the same problem but the 'switch flick' didn't work for them and the camera had to be repaired by a Nikon service center. Usually one of several circuit boards has been replaced. It is usually the same board for each particular model with the *(B)GLoD* problem.

For more, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/42614/15871) to [What to do when my Nikon DSLR back LED keeps blinking, draining the battery quickly?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42606/nikon-d90-back-led-keep-blinking/42614#42614)

Answer (score 2):

**Resolving a steady, non-blinking, "green light of death" on Nikon D7100**

After removing and reinserting the memory card with the camera on (by mistake), the green light stayed on, and screen on the top of the camera remained blank, no matter what I tried to do to fix it.

Finally had success with the following sequence, which is what Nikon recommends after upgrading firmware:

1. Turn camera on then off again
2. wait 5 seconds
3. remove battery or disconnect from AC
4. wait a bit
5. put battery back in
6. turn camera on

After this sequence, the camera functioned normally again.

If it doesn't work, do not despair. The procedure may have to be repeated multiple times with the battery left in or out for different amounts of time, as in the experience reported at [Nikon D7100 Green Light Stay On (Steady) When Off And Can't Be Turned On](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101232/75526).